# how to add hidden value from registeration from in db field in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have one registration form. I want to pass hidden value in that form. I have created one field in database 'lang'. In registration form I did like this: echo $form->hidden('lang', array('value' => '1')); But its not saving the value in db. Sorry I have no experience in cakephp, so please if anybody help me in this with all processes. Thanks

Comment: How about showing some code from your view (the form) and the controller logic where you save your data?

Answer (score 0):

You should not just pass hidden stuff through the form just for the heck of it.
If you can, add those values prior to actually saving.
See http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/ for details

Basically, you do:

```
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    $this->Post->create();
    // add the content before passing it on to the model
    $this->request->data['Post']['lang'] = '1';
    if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
        ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: How should I do in .ctp file?

Comment: when i dump posted values its showing that I am getting this value  ["lang"]=> string(1) "1", but its still not saving in the database

Comment: I am getting data till here if($this->save($data)) { // I have lang in here when i dump $data, but when i dump down   
 // Get the last inserted user
$user = $this->read(null, $this->getLastInsertID());
 // var_dump($user);
 exit;  here I have seen lang, i don't know why